# How should I insert a value into the "middle" of another?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, byte, idioms

I have two values v1 and v2 of types T1 and T2 respectively, with sizeof(T1)>sizeof(T2). Both types are plain-old-data. Now, I want to replace the k'th, k+1'th, ... k+sizeof(T2)-1'th bytes of v1 with the bytes of v2.

C++ doesn't offer this functionality inherently in the language, nor to my knowledge in the standard library (at least, not directly). What would be the best approach to implementing this generically? i.e. implementing:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void replace_bytes(T1& v1, T2 v2, std::size_t k)
```

or at least

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t k>
void replace_bytes(T1& v1, T2 v2)
```

?

My thoughts have been:

1. Reinterpret cast into arrays of bytes
2. Reinterpret cast into std::array of bytes
3. Use spans
4. Pointer arithmetic with the address of v1
5. For not-so-large types - reinterpret as unsigned integers and use bit operations: AND with a mask, shift, OR to combine the existing and replacement bits.

Notes:

- Of course if `k` is too high there will be UB here (or we could check it isn't too high).
- You may assume for the sake of simplicity that memory layout is little-endian.
- If alignment is an issue, be explicit about your choices regarding it.
- Efficiency/speed is of course a key issue.
- If your suggestion requires a newer C++ language standard, that's fine, but do mention it.
- It is important for the code be well-optimized during compilation.

Comment: why? even if it's POD, it's a weird request. and afaik would involve UB.

Comment: @appleapple: It's not that weird... Some instruction sets even have something like this as a native instruction (e.g. CUDA PTX's BFI - bit-field insert; although that's at the bit rather than byte level).

Comment: you can as simple use `memcpy`, it may work, or may not work. But still, why this is needed?

Comment: *Insert* or *replace*? The latter is easy and can be done using `char*` without breaking strict aliasing (and with a simple `std::memcpy` call). The former is going to be very hard. You have to take case to validate `k` of course, and not copy outside of `reinterpret_cast<char*>)(&v1) + sizeof(T1)`.

Comment: @appleapple: Indeed, `memcpy()` is another option. Example of this being useful: You want to set a value at an unaligned location in memory, but you can only make aligned writes; so you need to use the "enclosing" larger stretch of memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: replace. I don't want to "grow" the T1 value. If you think it's necessary, feel free to edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Please be less abstract if you have an actual concrete problem.  As written half your terms are underspecified, which makes your question both too broad and needlessly broad.  If your problem is literally "tell me every way to manipulate bits and bytes in C++" it is too broad a question.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I gave a signature of a very short function I want to implement. That is an actual concrete problem. There is already an actual concrete answer. Now, you could answer "I would do this differently depending on the actual types, not in one generic way" - and that's a valid answer/comment.

Comment: `void solve_my_problem(void*)` is a function signature.  Asking someone to implement it can be too broad if the problem is vague.  I could answer "there is no solution to the problem as described" in a bunch of different ways, or provide a dozen different solutions that disagree on what "best" means.  All eould be poor answers unless I read your mind.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: 1. I didn't ask for an implementation, I asked what the idiomatic approach to this was, seeing how I have several ideas regarding how to go about it. 2. Let's be practical. How would you suggest I narrow the scope of this question to get you to un-downvote?

Answer (score 3):

```
// needed include files
#include <iostream>  // for cout
#include <stdexcept> // for runtime_error
#include <cstring>   // for memcpy

// generic template function that takes 3 arguments
// 1 destination object
// 2 source object
// 3 from which byte to start in the destination
template<class T1, class T2>
void replace_bytes ( T1& t1, const T2& t2, std::size_t k )
{
// at compile time, store the size of T1 type in t1_size
   constexpr std::size_t t1_size = sizeof(T1);
// at compile time, store the size of T2 type in t2_size
   constexpr std::size_t t2_size = sizeof(T2);
// if we copy t2 bytes to t1, do we run out of memory ?
   if ( k + t2_size > t1_size )
   {
       throw std::runtime_error("Can't copy out of bounds.");
   }
// do the copying, casting is required for proper pointer arithmitic
   std::memcpy( (void*) (((char*)&t1)+k), (const void*) &t2, t2_size );
}

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  char c = 10;
  replace_bytes(x, c, 0);
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Clean version of code (no comments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>

template <class T1, class T2>
void replace_bytes ( T1& t1, const T2& t2, std::size_t k )
{
   constexpr std::size_t t1_size = sizeof(T1);
   constexpr std::size_t t2_size = sizeof(T2);

   if ( k + t2_size > t1_size )
   {
       throw std::runtime_error("Can't copy out of bounds.");
   }
   std::memcpy( (void*) (((char*)&t1)+k), (const void*) &t2, t2_size );
}

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  char c = 10;
  replace_bytes(x, c, 0);
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This won't do, because [compilers don't optimize it well enough](https://godbolt.org/z/_1YMIU).

Comment: And even if we [guarantee k is small enough, same problem](https://godbolt.org/z/zhXnRb).

Comment: Well, I filed a [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90271) about this.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for T1 sizes upto 8 bytes, and [seems to get optimized well enough](https://godbolt.org/z/4iKTck) on GCC, clang and MSVC - at least when inlining:

```
namespace detail {

template <unsigned NBytes> struct uint;

template<> struct uint<1> { using type = uint8_t;  };
template<> struct uint<2> { using type = uint16_t; };
template<> struct uint<4> { using type = uint32_t; };
template<> struct uint<8> { using type = uint64_t; };

} // namespace detail

template <unsigned NBytes>
using uint_t = typename detail::uint<NBytes>::type;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline void replace_bytes(T1& v1 ,T2 v2, std::size_t k)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2), "invalid sizes");
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<T1>::value, "T1 must be a trivial type");
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<T2>::value, "T2 must be a trivial type");
    auto shift_amount = k * CHAR_BIT;
    using uint_1_t = uint<sizeof(v1)>;
    using uint_2_t = uint<sizeof(v2)>;
    auto& v1_as_uint = *reinterpret_cast<uint_1_t*>(&v1);
    const auto& v2_as_uint = *reinterpret_cast<uint_2_t*>(&v2);

    auto v1_mask = ~( (uint_1_t{1} << (sizeof(T2) * CHAR_BIT) - 1) << shift_amount);
    auto shifted_v2 = uint_1_t{v2_as_uint} <<  shift_amount;
    v1_as_uint = (v1_as_uint & v1_mask ) | shifted_v2;
}
```

but I feel it's better to avoid out-parameters - and indeed, doing so allows the function implementation [to be strictly in-registers](https://godbolt.org/z/lUuWVN):

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 replace_bytes(T1 v1 ,T2 v2, std::size_t k)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2), "invalid sizes");
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<T1>::value, "T1 must be a trivial type");
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<T2>::value, "T2 must be a trivial type");
    auto shift_amount = k * CHAR_BIT;
    using uint_1_t = uint_t<sizeof(v1)>;
    using uint_2_t = uint_t<sizeof(v2)>;
    auto& v1_as_uint = *reinterpret_cast<uint_1_t*>(&v1);
    const auto& v2_as_uint = *reinterpret_cast<uint_2_t*>(&v2);

    auto v1_mask = ~( (uint_1_t{1} << (sizeof(T2) * CHAR_BIT) - 1) << shift_amount);
    auto shifted_v2 = uint_1_t{v2_as_uint} <<  shift_amount;
    return (v1_as_uint & v1_mask ) | shifted_v2;
}
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`ing the arguments to any unrelated type other than a `char`/`unsigned char` (or in C++17, `std::byte*`) violates C++'s strict-aliasing, and is undefined behavior. This _may_ work through compiler extensions, or in specific scenarios (e.g. `int` is input, casts to `int`), but will likely break with trivial `struct` types.

Comment: Also note that the above code breaks on the `return` if `T1` is not integral, even though `struct` types may be trivial. If the condition is meant to only be limited to integral types, you might want to assert on `std::is_integral` instead

Comment: @Bitwize: Why would this not work for non-integral types? I mean, other than the fact it may be UB...

Comment: I should probably clarify: I was referring to structural types, which the current code _can_ work with structural types, but (unless I'm mistaken) the type must be implicitly constructible from the _integral expression_ `(v1_as_uint & v1_mask ) | shifted_v2`. Often implicit construction is not desirable, which is why I assumed this was not intentional.

Comment: @Bitwize: Well, this is kind of implicit in my definition of the problem. If you can't construct implicitly from an integral expression, then sticking bytes in the middle doesn't make sense anyway.