# How can I work around GCC optimization-miss bug 90271?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

GCC versions released before May 2019 (and maybe later) fail to optimize this piece of code:

```
// Replace the k'th byte within an int
int replace_byte(int v1 ,char v2, size_t k) 
{
   memcpy( (void*) (((char*)&v1)+k) , &v2 , sizeof(v2) );
   return v1;
}
```

as can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zsUUQ-) (GodBolt): clang optimizes this code properly GCC and MSVC do not. This is [GCC bug 90271](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90271), which will at some point be fixed. But - it won't be fixed for GCC versions that are out today, and I want to write this code today...

So: Is there a workaround which will make GCC generate the same code as clang for this function, or at least - code of comparable performance, keeping data in registers and not resorting to pointers and the stack?

Notes:

- I marked this as C, since the code snippet is in C. I assume a workaround, if one exists, can also be implemented in C.
- I'm interested in optimizing both the non-inlined function and the inlined version.
- This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888672/how-should-i-insert-a-value-into-the-middle-of-another), but only regards GCC and the specific approach in the piece of code here; and is in C rather than C++.

Comment: why not just doing `((char*)&v1)[k] = v2` ? no need for `memcpy` here (note: this doesn't solve the optimization bug as goldbolt shows, so I deleted my answer)

Comment: even using a macro triggers the bug/does not optimize: `#define replace_bytes_4(v1 ,v2, k) ((char*)&v1)[k] = v2`

Comment: it can only be replaced if you onsider the constants. If you use real variables it will not be optimized this way. IMO useless optimisation in real programming. I bet no one will waste the time to do something with it.

Comment: It only replaces a single byte; why is it called replace_bytes?

Comment: @Jasen: Because in [the question where this came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888672/how-should-i-insert-a-value-into-the-middle-of-another) I was interested in replacing multiple bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This makes the non-inlined version a little longer, but the inlined version is optimized for all three compilers:

```
int replace_bytes(int v1 ,char v2, size_t k)
{
    return (v1 & ~(0xFF << k * 8)) | ((unsigned char)v2 << k * 8);
}
```

The cast of `v2` to an `unsigned char` before the shift is necessary if `char` is a signed type.  When that's the case, without the case `v2` will be sign extended to an integer, which will cause unwanted bits to be set to 1 in the result.

Comment: This inspired me to write a [partial answer for the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55910963/1593077)

Comment: Note that the original function will return different values depending on the endianness of the machine, whereas this one will not.  I'm not sure whether that was intended behavior in the original code.